# pip install pyswisseph giving error on windows 10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

When I run the command

```
pip install pyswisseph
```

to install the python extension of the [swiss ephemeris](http://pypi.org/project/pyswisseph/), its giving errors.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pyswisseph
Collecting pyswisseph
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/27/10ad652fa0e07fc89890142a6f900725e26cf02a24d8fd724015e08707b5/pyswisseph-2.00.00-2.tar.bz2
Building wheels for collected packages: pyswisseph
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyswisseph ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Narayana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wlypji8s\\pyswisseph\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Narayana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-f31zjcrt --python-tag cp37:
  Searching system libswe...
  pkg-config not found
  Using internal libswe
  c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:398: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.00.00-2' to '2.0.0.post2'
    normalized_version,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'swisseph' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libswe
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\swephelp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibswe -Iswephelp -Ic:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" /Tcpyswisseph.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyswisseph.obj -std=gnu99
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
  pyswisseph.c
  c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  **----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyswisseph**
  Running setup.py clean for pyswisseph
Failed to build pyswisseph
Installing collected packages: pyswisseph
  Running setup.py install for pyswisseph ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Narayana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wlypji8s\\pyswisseph\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Narayana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-00ch1s58\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Searching system libswe...
    pkg-config not found
    Using internal libswe
    c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:398: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.00.00-2' to '2.0.0.post2'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'swisseph' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\libswe
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\swephelp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibswe -Iswephelp -Ic:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" /Tcpyswisseph.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyswisseph.obj -std=gnu99
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
    pyswisseph.c
    c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    **----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\narayana\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Narayana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wlypji8s\\pyswisseph\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Narayana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-00ch1s58\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Narayana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wlypji8s\pyswisseph\**

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to run the pyswisseph package is to use it on an Ubuntu VM using the free Google Colab platform. For a sample code, please follow [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HaPAIYGj0cYGYnhJ227I3vwZYuQ8V_OG) and then create your own copy of the notebook file and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, by switching to an UNIX-y system such as Linux or macOS (or maybe with a GCC-based toolchain like MinGW on Windows).

The package does not seem compatible with Windows/Visual Studio; the `setup.py` file is chock full of assumptions that only make sense on UNIXes.

EDIT: The package works fine on macOS:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin xx 17.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.6.0: Tue May  8 15:22:16 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.61.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ pip install pyswisseph
Collecting pyswisseph
  Downloading... (458kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyswisseph
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyswisseph ... done
Successfully built pyswisseph
Installing collected packages: pyswisseph
Successfully installed pyswisseph-2.0.0.post2
```

Comment: For curiosity, is MacOS likely supported?

Comment: @Dyno Seems so.

Comment: From README.TXT: *With Windows, it is recommended to use MSVC 201x or MinGW, with help of the CMake build system.* As for MacOS — why not, isn't it unixish enough?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to get the module working in windows. we have to use an unofficial windows binary , wheel file from 
' https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/'.
there are different wheel's for different versions of python and updates of the module. i used :pyswisseph‑2.5.1.post0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl. use the wheel which suits your python/windows version
Solution: all you have to do is open command window, type 
' pip install pyswisseph‑2.5.1.post0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl' 
and it gets installed.